# What about the questions that are not answered

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unanswered questions which author don’t care about, vote for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106584/unanswered-questions-which-author-dont-care-about-vote-for-deletion)

What happen to those questions that are not answered or to those no body gets solution. Shouldn't they be closed or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the contrary, you should place a bounty on such a question.